# Idea in order to address lack of scrollbar in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, flutter-web

I am new to flutter and using it for web. I see that there is no built in scrollbar when the page overflows the viewport

Would it be possible to somehow have a javascript script in the html that would check the height of the content periodically and add/remove scroll bar as necessary?

Does this make any sense?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean [Listview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)?

Comment: @P4yam for what I see ListView only allows scrolling with your mouse wheel, but there is no scrollbar in browser. Am I wrong? I am trying to see if it is possible to have the browser scrollbar somehow... IDK

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if its what you want but if you wrap your `Listview` with `Scrollbar` then you get the result you want:

```
Scrollbar(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 20,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Item= ${index + 1}"),),),
)
```

You can find more [here](https://medium.com/flutterflakes/flutter-tip-show-scrollbar-in-listview-71fc504c71e5)

Comment: Yes. It's good, I had read there was no scrollbar support. I would rather have the native browser scroll, this will do fine

Comment: Hi @P4yam, the problem is this scrollbar is not draggable. I mean it is but works funkyly, not usable to drag

Comment: @user3808307 unfortunately i dont know much about flutter web. it may be better to ask your question in flutter github